# Removing kernels automatically

Tags: 16.04, kernel

Just like the title says. Is there a way to do it?

Usually after a kernel update I run

> sudo apt autoremove

and it will remove older kernels. A bit annoying because it consumes too much space on my drive.

Comment: Please let's focus on the topic of automatic removal, and not mark is as a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu). Also, I think it should be 'automatic removal of old kernels and headers'. Both take disk space when a lot is accumulated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels. Automatic Maintenance section